# Why doesn't "Keep offline" in Google Docs always let me access my document?

Tags: nexus-5, google-drive, offline

I have a Nexus 5 and I am having trouble understanding what the **Keep offline** option in Google Docs does.

For example, I have a Shopping List document.

Sometimes when I am at the supermarket, I have no mobile signal, but I still want to be able to view my shopping list (understanding that it may not be the latest version that I edited on my PC).  So I turned on the **Keep offline** option.

[image]

Most of the time when I try to access this document, and I have no mobile signal, I get an error that the document cannot be accessed (oddly enough, I can't reproduce the error now, which is why I can't be more specific regarding the error message).

Is there something else I need to be aware of when using this feature?  Or should turning this option on allow me to access the document in all situations?

Comment: You should be able to access any file when "Keep offline" is turned on provided that the file is downloaded/accessed atleast once.

Comment: @MANI - I have definitely accessed the file at least once, so I can rule that out.  My Nexus has a lot of quirks that other owners don't seem to experience; I wonder if it's time for a factory reset?

Comment: There is nothing much to say about this feature any more. It would be easy to tell something if you can reproduce the "error message". Or just reset the Google Keep by clearing app data/cache rather than factory reset. But it's your wish.

Comment: I don't know if this issue is still applicable after some update to Docs app, but try following what [Google Support for Docs says](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2375012) first. Some steps might be different (it seems not up-to-date), but maybe it can show the cause why sometimes you couldn't access it offline.